# Unable to set remote SDP offer for H264 encoded video on Huawei devices

Tags: android, video, webrtc, gstreamer, h.264

I'm developing a WebRTC video call app (one-way video and two-way audio) for Android with prebuilt package
`org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006`. I'm stuck with an error from this lib that states:

```
LS_ERROR
tag: webrtc_video_engine.cc 
message: (line 745): No video codecs supported.
```

after trying to set a remote SDP offer:

```
v=0
o=- 955391267744368972 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=ice-options:trickle
a=group:BUNDLE video0 audio1 application2
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=ice-ufrag:NwMv07hmtKD9s8EFikQCvqv7JvMpVhv4
a=ice-pwd:[xxx]
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=framerate:30
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42c01f;sprop-parameter-sets=J0LAH5WgKA9oQAAAAwBAAAAPOSAACYlgABqz+97gHiRNQA==,KM4fIA==
a=ssrc:2596331602 msid:user823769301@host-4c0ea8a4 webrtctransceiver0
a=ssrc:2596331602 cname:user823769301@host-4c0ea8a4
a=mid:video0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 [xxx]
m=audio 0 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 97
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=ice-ufrag:NwMv07hmtKD9s8EFikQCvqv7JvMpVhv4
a=ice-pwd:[xxx]
a=bundle-only
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:97 OPUS/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
a=fmtp:97 sprop-maxcapturerate=48000;sprop-stereo=0
a=ssrc:235675792 msid:user823769301@host-4c0ea8a4 webrtctransceiver1
a=ssrc:235675792 cname:user823769301@host-4c0ea8a4
a=mid:audio1
a=fingerprint:sha-256 [xxx]
m=application 0 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=ice-ufrag:NwMv07hmtKD9s8EFikQCvqv7JvMpVhv4
a=ice-pwd:[xxx]
a=bundle-only
a=mid:application2
a=sctp-port:5000
a=fingerprint:sha-256 [xxx]
```

It gets me confused as `android.media.MediaCodecList` contains `OMX.google.h264` and `HardwareVideoDecoderFactory::supportedCodecs` contains `name: H264; params: {level-asymmetry-allowed=1, profile-level-id=42e01f, packetization-mode=1}`

I'm using Honor 7X and Huawei P10 and I'm aware that their chipsets lack the hardware H264 encoding which is fine as I **do not stream any video** from the Android device.

As a video streaming device I use RaspberryPi build with GStreamer as media processing pipeline. The output of `v4l2-ctl --list-formats`:

```
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'YU12' (Planar YUV 4:2:0)
    [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
    [2]: 'RGB3' (24-bit RGB 8-8-8)
    [3]: 'JPEG' (JFIF JPEG, compressed)
    [4]: 'H264' (H.264, compressed)
    [5]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
    [6]: 'YVYU' (YVYU 4:2:2)
    [7]: 'VYUY' (VYUY 4:2:2)
    [8]: 'UYVY' (UYVY 4:2:2)
    [9]: 'NV12' (Y/CbCr 4:2:0)
    [10]: 'BGR3' (24-bit BGR 8-8-8)
    [11]: 'YV12' (Planar YVU 4:2:0)
    [12]: 'NV21' (Y/CrCb 4:2:0)
    [13]: 'RX24' (32-bit XBGR 8-8-8-8)
```

And this is my pipeline definition:

```
#define RTP_CAPS_OPUS "application/x-rtp,media=audio,encoding-name=OPUS,payload="
#define RTP_CAPS_H264 "application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload="

"v4l2src ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! v4l2h264enc ! video/x-h264,level=(string)3.1,stream-format=(string)byte-stream ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! "  
        "" RTP_CAPS_H264 "96 ! sendrecv. "
        "alsasrc ! queue ! webrtcdsp noise-suppression-level=3 ! webrtcechoprobe ! audioamplify amplification=1 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! queue ! opusenc ! rtpopuspay ! "
        "queue ! " RTP_CAPS_OPUS "97 ! sendrecv. "
```

My guess is that the H264 profiles are different (RPi: `42c01f`; Huawei: `42e01f`). Also difference in the format's payload might be in a way (`96` vs. `100` respectively), however I don't have any clue about the significance of these differences.

My second guess is that I should not set `a=sendrecv` in both clients video media description, but I can't figure out how to accomplish that via WebRTC Android API. Should I put `sendonly` for RPi then?

And finally, why should I set the `VideoEncoderFactory` event though I don't encode any video? Without explicitly passing a `DefaultVideoEncoderFactory` to `PeerConnection` I cannot establish any connection at all.

Would you be able to point me in the right direction? Any clues, experiences and documentation pieces are highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? It looks as if you would use gstreamer on the Android side. Up to now I was not able to answer an incoming offer with a H.264 pipeline properly (was using a Python app). I think this is a gstreamer flaw

Comment: What I managed to identify is that gstreamer on the other client forces the Android client (we use pre-compiled webrtc interface from google, no explicit gstreamer dependency) to look for the video encoder anyway. The potential solution is to set custom RTCRtpTransceiver with RTCRtpTransceiverDirection = sendonly on the other client side. But we didn't manage to implement it yet as it appears non trivial in gstreamer itself.

Comment: @decades we managed to solve this

Answer (score 0):

After some struggle we managed to fix the problem. The solution is to force the `sendonly` flag on the video media SDP part. This can be done in two ways (in my case both of these were needed to successfully bypass the lacking H264 encoder on Huawei):

### **'Offer to receive' attribute**

When creating a SDP offer you can put an attribute to `MediaConstraints` that will enforce proper SDP generation

```kotlin
val mediaConstraints = MediaConstraints()     
mediaConstraints.mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"))
peerConnection.createOffer(observer, mediaConstraints)
```

This way the device will generate a list of all video formats that it could decode and put it in SDP video request with `recvonly`.

---

### **Gstreamer pipeline definition**

To enforce `sendonly` on gstreamer side we came up with kinda hacky solution

```c
GstSDPMedia *video_media = (GstSDPMedia *)offer->sdp->medias[0].data;
const GstSDPAttribute *direction_attribute = gst_sdp_media_get_attribute(video_media, 5);
gst_sdp_attribute_set(direction_attribute, "sendonly", NULL);
```

This results in correct attribute being set on SDP offer/answer from gstreamer and does not force the device to look for video encoders.